# Slider active or inactive color buggy/turning transparent?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble with setting the Slider widget's color, be it the active or inactive color.

```
Color color = const Color(0x00ff9f1c);
```

```
Slider(
              value: sliderValue,
              activeColor: color,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 100.0,
              divisions: 2000,
              label: sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sliderValue = value;
                  InputVariables.distance = sliderValue;
                });
              }),
```

This causes my slider to go transparent in the *active color* section like this:

[image]

If I set the `activeColor` to a **Colors**.*somecolor* it works, so is it an issue with the Color class being incompatible? I have tried Hot reloading, restarting, and rebuilding.

I am trying to get the `activeColor` to work without this bug, looking something like this as the result (not the exact color I want), but by using my `color` *const* I have declared and initialized.

[image]

Comment: Can you include what are you trying to archive?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh My bad if I was vague, I simply want to change the `activeColor` to a custom `Color` I create. Right now it works if it is set to a `Colors` class like; `activeColor: Colors.amber` https://i.imgur.com/Zs7Jk2z.png. However as in the question, when I set it to my `const Color color`, it bugs out and goes somewhat transparent? I am just looking to fix this.

Comment: Can you update the question of what are you looking for

Comment: I don't understand what the question lacked, I simply wanted to fix the bug shown in the image. But for your request, I have added an explanation for how it should look without this bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you attached image, use `activeColor` and `inactiveColor` to get the result.

```dart
Slider(
    value: sliderValue,
    activeColor: Colors.amber,
    //inactiveColor: color,
    inactiveColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
    min: 0.0,
    max: 100.0,
    label: sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),
    divisions: 2000,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        sliderValue = value;
      });
    }),
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but it was already working for me like in my question if I use the `Colors` class, even if I only used `activeColor`. May I ask why a `Color` class object does not work for the slider's colors, but rather only the `Colors` class?

Comment: It works as color object, about your `color = const Color(0x00ff9f1c);` It is transparent. That's why you can't get any visual output. Also for attached result image, you need to use `inactiveColor`

Comment: Thank you! I had copied the hex value from another website but I didn't pay any heed to its data, so the first two `00` were there alpha values, so changing them to `ff` resulting in `color = const Color(0xffff9f1c);` worked after a hot restart. Silly mistake, thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you out; Sometimes we just need an extra pair of eyes to be sure